# Why does this work? Are Java rounding down?

Tags: java, string, substring

```
public class StringTest{
  public static void main(String[] args){
       String a = "Aphex";
       int len  = a.length();
       int lenA = len/2-1;
       int lenB = len/2+2;
       if(len%2==0){
           System.out.println("Number of letters has to be odd");
       }else{
           System.out.println(a.substring(lenA, lenB))   }}}

Output:
phe
```

This simple code can take any String with an odd number of letters and find the three center ones. My question is – why is it *center* to go down one spot from the middle (`len/2-1)` and then two spots up? It does not work the other way around (`len/2-2` to `len/2+1`).

Are Java always rounding down?

Comment: I did! Which added more confusion. You are landing in the middle of a letter/number. I'm very new to Java, so I'm just wondering if Java always rounds down the same way for future reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are conducting divisions in an integer context. When dividing two int, only the integer part of the result will be kept, and the remainder will be discarded. E.g., `29/10` will result in `2`.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is – why is it center to go down one spot from the middle (`len/2-1`) and then two spots up? It does not work the other way around (`len/2-2` to `len/2+1`).

This happens because the range taken by `substring()` includes the start index but does *not* include the end index. To quote the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)):

> The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.

Thus the actual range is `[len/2-1; len/2+1]` and is symmetric around the central character, `len/2`.

(And yes, when you divide an odd integer by two, the result is rounded towards zero.)